# About ASME citation style

Tags: bibtex

[image]

So ASME provides `asmems4.bst` to generate a citation style which contradicts their requirement online: https://libraryguides.missouri.edu/mae/asmecitation.

I was trying to tinker the `bst` file, i.e. change the `FUNCTION {output.nonnull}` to following. Although it did not work quite right as shown in the pictures.

```
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
    { ", " *  write$
      newline$
      "\newblock " write$
    }
    { output.state before.all =
        'write$
        { ", " *  write$ }
      if$
    }
    if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
```

I really need the commas inside the quotes. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your query is somewhat confusing: The title mentions something about citation style, yet the body of the posting is not about citations in the body of the docment; instead, it appears to be about the formatting of the bibliographic items. Please clarify. Please also state explicitly what the issues are, either with the citation call-outs or the formatting of the bibliographic items (or both?).

Answer (score 2):

ASME's citation style for conferences and journals, as posted on their web site, does not match the old `asmems4.bst`.  That style is based on ASME's recommendations during the 1990's.

There is a newer .bst for ASME conferences here: https://ctan.org/pkg/asmeconf

There is a newer .bst for ASME journals here:https://ctan.org/pkg/asmejour

Both of these `.bst` files were designed around the reference formats on ASME's web pages in early 2019.